# Web Mining with Python

Tags: python, web, web-scraping

I am planning to scraping exchange rates with Python.After I get the raw data from HTML pages, what kind of processing will I need to get prepared for my output/visualization? Will I need some text processing, NLP algorithms, graph processing or cleaning of your data?

Comment: it depends what is your data structure in html page. first you should see what you need in html page then extract it. one of the best tools for extracting data from web page is Beautifulsoup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you need but according to your comment, you can use following code to extract all data from that page:

```
import urllib
import bs4
url=urllib.urlopen('http://www.tcmb.gov.tr/kurlar/201501/02012015.xml').read().decode('Windows-1252')
soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(url)
data=soup.get_text(' ')
print(data)
```

this script wrote on python 2.7 and you need to install beautifulsoup4.

or you can use below code. in this code I extract rates for us dollar:

```
import urllib.request
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
url=urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.tcmb.gov.tr/kurlar/201501/02012015.xml').read()
f=open('data.xml','w+b')
f.write(url)
f.close()
tree = ET.parse('data.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for i in range(len(root[0])):
           print(root[0][i].text)
```

or you can extract all rates for ForexBuying:

```
for i in root.iter('ForexBuying'):
    print(i.text)
```